# Using Regex to get multiple data on single line by scraping stocks from yahoo

Tags: python, regex, urllib, scrape, stock

```
import urllib
import re

stocks_symbols = ['aapl', 'spy', 'goog', 'nflx', 'msft']

for i in range(len(stocks_symbols)):
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen("https://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=" + stocks_symbols[i])
    htmltext = htmlfile.read(htmlfile)
    regex = '<span id="yfs_l84_' + stocks_symbols[i] + '">(.+?)</span>'
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    price = re.findall(pattern, htmltext)

    regex1 = '<h2 id="yui_3_9_1_9_(.^?))">(.+?)</h2>'
    pattern1 = re.compile(regex1)
    name1 = re.findall(pattern1, htmltext)
    print "Price of", stocks_symbols[i].upper(), name1, "is", price[0]
```

I guess the problem is in `regex1`,

```
regex1 = '<h2 id="yui_3_9_1_9_(.^?))">(.+?)</h2>'
```

I tried reading documentation but was unable to figure it out.

In this program I trying to scrape **Stock-Name** and **Stock-Price** with input of **Stock-Symbol** as a list.

what I think I am doing is to passing 2 *(.+?)* in one variable which seems incorrect.

***OutPut:***

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Py\stock\stocks.py", line 14, in <module>
    pattern1 = re.compile(regex1)
  File "C:\canopy-1.4.0.1938.win-x86\lib\re.py", line 190, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\canopy-1.4.0.1938.win-x86\lib\re.py", line 242, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
error: nothing to repeat
```

Comment: Sorry, we don't use regex in web scraping - we use `lxml`, `BeautifulSoup`, `PyQuery`, etc so we can answer for your question.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at this: https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/ You can access yahoo's stock infomrmationn via an SQL-like API

Comment: I check page and I don't see `<h2>` with `id="yui_3_9_1_9_` - there are only `<script>` with `id="yui_3_9_1_9_`. Maybe `<h2>` are generated by javascript then you can need something more then `urllib` or `requests`

Comment: I actually wanted to scrape Name from symbol, like with AAPL it should say 'Apple Inc. (AAPL)'. And i got it by applying all html code above it.
`regex1 = '<div class="title"><h2>(.+?)</h2> <span class="rtq_exch"><span class="rtq_dash">-</span>NasdaqGS  </span><span class="wl_sign"></span></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^` matches the start of a string and a `?` after that is not a legal regex. If you change your regex to `regex1 = '(.+?)'` it should work. Note that you also had one parenthesis too much.

Furthermore there is a better way to get yahoo's stock information. You can query a lot of tables (including stock info) with [YQL](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) and there is also a [YQL-Console](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/) where you can try out your queries.

The result you get from there is JSON or XML, which can be handled pretty good via some python libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the price  using BeautifulSoup:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
stocks_symbols = ['aapl', 'spy', 'goog', 'nflx', 'msft']

for stock in stocks_symbols:
    htmlfile = requests.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/q?s={}".format(stock))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlfile.content)
    price = [x.text for x in soup.findAll("span",id="yfs_l84_{}".format(stock))]
    print ("Price of {}  is {}".format(stock.upper(), price[0]))
Price of AAPL  is 94.03
Price of SPY  is 198.20
Price of GOOG  is 584.73
Price of NFLX  is 472.35
Price of MSFT  is 41.80
```

Comment: Nice :) I was working on example with lxml.

Comment: @furas, thanks, I don't think the source has the other pattern as far as I can see

Comment: BeautifulSoup has a lot of bugs, even in bs4. I wound up going back to lxml (shudder) when BS wouldn't parse an entire webpage for the dozenth time due to god-knows-what.

Answer (score 0):

Example with `requests` and `lxml` and `css selection`

```
import requests
import lxml, lxml.cssselect

stocks_symbols = ['aapl', 'spy', 'goog', 'nflx', 'msft']

for symbol in stocks_symbols:

    r = requests.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=" + symbol)
    html = lxml.html.fromstring(r.text)

    price = html.cssselect('span#yfs_l84_' + symbol)
    print '%s: %s' % (symbol.upper(), price[0].text)

    # there is no `h2` with `id` started wiht "yui_3_9_1_9_"
    # so I can't test this part of code

    #names = html.cssselect('h2[id^="yui_3_9_1_9_"]')
    #for x in names:
    #    print x.text, x.attrib('id')[len('yui_3_9_1_9_'):]
```

result:

```
AAPL: 94.03
SPY: 198.20
GOOG: 584.73
NFLX: 472.35
MSFT: 41.80
```

Comment: That's a neat piece of code but the OP was asking for a way to integrate regex. That cssselect stuff doesn't look like regex, just string concatenation